# Is it possible to use two different API Keys for two different services (methods in controllers) in same project in Azure Api Management?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-api-management

We have a .net Core Project and we want to publish with APIM Azure Api Management. But we want one of the services have to be accesed with one api key and all the others services have to be accesed with other api key.

How it is possible to achieve this with Azure Api Management?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below helps your problem ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Any update about this post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it by setting separate subscription key for different Apis in your API Management.

First, you need to check if the api in your API Management is enabled with "**Subscription required**".

[image]

Then click "**Subscriptions**" tab, add a subscription and select the api which you want to use this subscription key like below screenshot:

[image]

After create the subscription, it will generate new "Primary key" like below screenshot. Then you can use this key as `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` in header when you request your api.

[image]